# Hive - create table

Tags: hiveql

I need to create a table in hive to insert a data like the one below:

Column 1   --    account id String(11 characters)
Column 2   --    Age int
Column 3   --    duplicate account_id

The data is stored in a text file delimited by spaces, but the last column will have multiple values, hence doing querying I will need to eliminate that row  if the value is present in that column

Example text file:

Thomsxx3125 25 Davidxx3125 Raghuxx3125 Vijayxx3125 Gracexx3125

Appreciate your help on this please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create duplicate column names. 
Here is a query that will work:

```
create table if not exists name_of_table
(
account_id string comment '11 characters',
age int,
account_id2 string
)
fields terminated by ' '
stored as textfile;
```

You can also refer to the official documentation for Hive:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable